# Logitech MX Master 2s on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, mouse, logitech

I have recently switched to a dual boot system to get more into Linux, and have been using it mainly ever since. There is one problem, however, that prevents me from using it all the time. I cannot seem to keep my Bluetooth mouse (MX Master 2S) connected to my laptop (Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15 AMD). I have upgraded to a more recent kernel (5.10.0-051000-generic) to fix some other issues the laptop had, and now all works fine except for my mouse.

I can connect the mouse all fine, but once I suspend my laptop or turn it off, I have to reconnect it all over again, and this is far from ideal. I do not need all the functions off the mouse, but I would love for it to work properly, since I see myself going back to windows just for the mouse working properly there.

So far I have trusted the mouse, used blueman to connect it, manually configured the mouse using buetoothctl, and more. Still I cannot figure it out. Does anyone have the same issue, or maybe fixed it already? I would love to hear from you!

Comment: I have this mouse too, but i use the unifying receiver for the connection. This was the only way to ensure that the mouse (and the associated keyboard) also worked in the BIOS and the bootloader.

Comment: @bbjoverbeek try https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/